# Error message is showed in Danish, not English

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

So I'm working on this ASP.NET MVC 5 project and everytime I bump into an error I get my error message showed in Danish. I want it to be displayed in English. I don't know how it changed out of sudden. anyone know how I can change it back to English, please.[image]

Comment: Just checking maybe your browser has a translator on.....

Comment: Add <system.web>
   <globalization uiCulture="en-US" />
</system.web> in Web.config. Thank you.